# XNA C# Inheritance stops object from being drawn

Tags: c#, inheritance, xna

**Base Class**

Notice the draw method. It exists and the syntax is sound.

```
public class defaultObject
{
    // variables are here

    public defaultObject(Vector2 nPos, float nRotation, Texture2D nTexture, int nWidth, int nHeight)
    {
        // constructor business
    }

    public virtual void update()
    {
        rectangle = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, width, height);
        origin = new Vector2(texture.Width / 2f, texture.Height / 2f);
    }

    public virtual void draw(SpriteBatch spatch)
    {
        spatch.Draw(texture, rectangle, null, Color.Green, rotation, origin, SpriteEffects.None, 1f);
    }
}
```

**Derived Class**

No need to override the draw method, only the update method.

```
public class block: defaultObject
{
    public block(Vector2 nPos, float nRotation, Texture2D nTexture, int nWidth, int nHeight)
        : base(nPos, nRotation, nTexture, nWidth, nHeight)
    { }

    public override void update()
    {
        if (rotation > (float)(Math.PI * 2))
        {
            rotation = 0;
        }

        if (rotation < 0)
        {
            rotation = (float)Math.PI * 2;
        }
    }
}
```

**Game1.cs**

**Assume all the other XNA necessities are there, I'm keeping it simple for reading**

**PROBLEM:** When I attempt to draw block a, it doesn't appear. Why?

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    block a;

        a = new block(new Vector2(windowSize.X / 4f, windowSize.X / 2), 3.1415f, rectangleTexture, 300, 50);
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        //keyboard input to manipulate a is here

        a.update();
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        a.draw(spriteBatch);
    }
}
```

Before I introduced this inheritance business, the block was visible.

Comment: Why is defaultObject.draw() set to virtual?

Comment: I may need to change it further into development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call draw, it uses the metheod from the base class `defaultObject`, which is fine but that method needs the rectangle and origin info which has never been set.

You need to call `base.Update()` at the end of `block.Update()` or move the rectangle/origin setting to the constructor.

Comment: IntelliSense doesn't suggest 'base.Update()' after a.Update().

Comment: no, it should be inside `a.Update()`, but at the end of the code block. just like the standard Game1.Update does when you start a new project. You want that same functionality

Comment: Ah, I misread your text. "at the end of block.Update()" was interpreted as 'block.Update().base.Update()' which looks odd, obviously, but I understand that you meant at the end of _the base method_. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call

```
base.Update()
```

Maybe object is drown outside the screen because of unset "rectangle" and "origin"

Comment: Thanks! I called base.Update() inside the overrided method, it works now.